# DQL Symfony 2, Set boolean value

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

i have a problem about DQL Symfony 2, i want to set the first value in my select. The value is boolean, but i can't do this. this is my code :

```
    public function findAllMenuListForMenuGroup(){
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('a.id, a.lft, a.lvl, a.rgt, a.name, a.title, true as value, a.description')
        ->from(Menu::class,'a')
        ->orderBy('a.root, a.lft','ASC')
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getArrayResult();
}
```

this code is error but i don't know the problems, look the code "true as value", i feel there is the problem, anyone can help me ?

the error is :

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 51: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable
>   | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration |
>   PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got
>   'true'

```
    /**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Menu", inversedBy="menuGroup")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="administration_menu_group_details")
 */
private $menu;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="menuGroup")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=1000)
 */
private $description;
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: You can specify only one field at time with the orderby method.  You can use the addorderby method in order to add another one

Comment: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 51: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got 'true'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
1 as value
```

instead of

```
true as value
```

Probably you must enclose in " character.

Also, You need to use addOrderBy instead of orderBy as follow:

```
    ->addOrderBy('a.root','ASC')
    ->addOrderBy('a.lft','ASC')
```

Instead of:

```
    ->orderBy('a.root, a.lft','ASC')
```

Hope this help

Comment: your sugestion is worked but i get type data is string not a boolean. I need a boolean

Comment: hi @RachmatChang with our without the `"`?

Comment: i just try use '' and not use '' and the result is still String @Matteo

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine Uses it's own aliases. You can't use "as" here.

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('a.id, a.lft, a.lvl, a.rgt, a.name, a.title, a.true, a.description')
        ->from(Menu::class,'a')
        ->orderBy('a.root,'ASC')
        ->orderBy('a.lft,'ASC')
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getArrayResult();
```

Comment: Can I have your entity please?

Comment: is "true" a property?

Comment: I don't think this is supported. You can always run raw sql using doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it in DQL.
Add a method to your object that is returning always `true`. Then remove `select` from your DQL.

Comment: please give me a example

Comment: public function getFoo() { return true; }